# select the locale based on the current date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

hi im trying to formulate a query that return the locale of an employee based on the effective date.

```
declare @locale table
(
  [locale_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1), 
  [locale_name] [varchar](50)
)

declare @employees table
(
  [employee_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
  [employee_number] [varchar](20),
  [employee_name] [varchar](50),
  [employee_dept] [varchar](50),
  [report_to] [int]
)

declare @employee_locale table
(
  [employee_locale_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
  [locale_id] [int],
  [employee_id] [int],
  [effective_date] [datetime]
)

insert into @locale values ('CST')
insert into @locale values ('PHT')

insert into @employees  values ('812621','Davolio Nancy','UCC GTT','0')
insert into @employees  values ('811363','Fuller Andrew','UCC GTT','1')
insert into @employees  values ('811397','Leverling  Janet','UCC GTT','1')
insert into @employees  values ('814495','Peacock  Margaret','UCC GTT','2')

insert into @employee_locale   values ('1','1','May 14 2012 12:00AM')
insert into @employee_locale   values ('1','2','Apr 12 2010 12:00AM')
insert into @employee_locale   values ('1','3','Apr 26 2010 12:00AM')
insert into @employee_locale   values ('1','4','Sep  9 2013 12:00AM')

insert into @employee_locale   values ('2','1','June 14 2012 12:00AM')
insert into @employee_locale   values ('1','1','July 14 2012 12:00AM')
insert into @employee_locale   values ('2','1','August 14 2012 12:00AM')
insert into @employee_locale   values ('1','1','September 14 2012 12:00AM')

--select * from @locale
--select * from @employees
--select * from @employee_locale

declare @current_datetime datetime
set @current_datetime = '07/01/2012'

SELECT employees.employee_id, employees.employee_number, 
  employees.employee_name, employees.employee_dept, employees.report_to, 
  employee_locale.effective_date, locale.locale_name
FROM @employees employees
INNER JOIN @employee_locale employee_locale ON employees.employee_id = employee_locale.employee_id
INNER JOIN @locale locale ON employee_locale.locale_id = locale.locale_id
WHERE employees.employee_number = '812621'

SELECT employees.employee_id, employees.employee_number,
  employees.employee_name, employees.employee_dept, employees.report_to, 
  employee_locale.effective_date, locale.locale_name
FROM @employees employees
INNER JOIN @employee_locale employee_locale ON employees.employee_id = employee_locale.employee_id
INNER JOIN @locale locale ON employee_locale.locale_id = locale.locale_id
WHERE employee_locale.effective_date >= @current_datetime 
  and employee_locale.effective_date <= @current_datetime
  and employees.employee_number = '812621'
```

for instance.  if today is '07/01/2012', i wanted to get the locale of Davolio Nancy on that specific period.   in this case it will return the second record.

please help.  thanks.

Comment: Could you describe why second record is the result? What is logic? Nearest following date? May 14 < arg = June 1  > June 14?

Comment: employee_locale contains all change in locale for a specifice employee with the given effective date. assuming today is 07/01/2012,  Davolio Nancy locale was in PHT.

Comment: oh i has mixed up june and july... now looks like i get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CROSS APPLY` and `ORDER BY [date] DESC` will locate last date before `@current_datetime` supplied:

```
SELECT
  e.employee_id, e.employee_number, 
  e.employee_name, e.employee_dept, e.report_to, 
  el.effective_date, loc.locale_name
FROM @employees e
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 el.effective_date, el.locale_id
  FROM @employee_locale el
  WHERE el.employee_id = e.employee_id
    AND el.effective_date <= @date
  ORDER BY el.effective_date desc
) el
INNER JOIN @locale loc ON loc.locale_id = el.locale_id
where e.employee_number = '812621'
```

use `OUTER APPLY` and `LEFT JOIN` if `NULL` locale allowed